# strtok function php not working

Tags: php, strtok

I have the following file, saved as a .php:

```
<head>
<title>String Manipulation</title>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<?php
$words = "Hello how are you";

$token = strtok($feedback, ' ');
echo $token.'<br />';

while ($token!='')
{
    $token = strtok(' ');
    echo $token.'<br />';
};
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I am reading a book on php and they have this example and claim that it should print each 'token'(In this case i think that would be each word?) on a new line, but when i run this code nothing happens. What am i doing incorrect? PS: I am running this with MAMP if that matters

Comment: `$feedback` -> `$words` ?

Comment: where does `$feedback` come from?

Comment: thanks everyone. That was a silly mistake, they used $feedback in the example and decided to use $words for some reason

Answer (score 0):

This code should be:

```
<head>
<title>String Manipulation</title>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<?php
$words = "Hello how are you";

$token = strtok($words, ' ');
echo $token.'<br />';

while ($token!='')
{
    $token = strtok(' ');
    echo $token.'<br />';
};
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$words = "Hello how are you";
// Change $feedback to $words
$token = strtok($words, ' ');       
echo $token.'<br />';

while ($token!=''){
    $token = strtok(' ');
    echo $token.'<br />';
}
?>
```